# Utf-8 encoding for PHP-scripts creates "headers already sent"

Tags: php, ftp, utf-8

If I upload php files that are encoded in UTF-8, instead of ANSI, it creates problems with "headers already sent" on the server.

vi shows {feff}  at the start and nano does not show the \ at the start. When I remove the {feff} manually in vi, it works fine. But after every new FTP upload, this is added again.

This also happens to .html and .ctp files, but so far never has been a problem.

Comment: Have you tried uploading your files using the binary transfer type instead of the ASCII one?

Comment: Try uploading "good" files? ie files that don't begin with buggy characters (I saw some windows text editors who had bad behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruct your editor to save `UTF-8` files without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I already used to use "UTF-8" in notepad++. I have set notepad++ to use UTF-8 without a BOM.